# How to load different video for mobile devices and desktop web version?

Tags: html5-video, responsive-design

I am developing a website using Responsive Web Technology and HTML5. I have a HD quality video of 720x576 resolution which I am embedding using HTML5 `<video>` and                `<source>` tags.

But as its a very heavy video so I don't want to resize it for Ipad and mobile devices. Rather I would like to load a different video of 320x240 resolution when the site is opened in Mobile/Ipad devices. I have used the media query in `<source>` tag but its not workin, below is the sample of the code I have tried with.

```
<video controls>
   <source src="mySmallVideo.webm" type="video/webm" media="all and (max-width:600px)">
   <source src="myVideo.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Any idea how I can achieve this requirement, if its possible with Jquery and javascript then please provide me with some ideas or if possible with some links.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of one technique with two approaches.

First of all on your server side you could detect the user agent of the browser and if it matches against a mobile browser then you could change the src of the video to be your lower resolution one.

The second approach would be to use javscript / jQuery to detect if the user is using a mobile browser and do the same thing, change the src of the video to be the lower resolution one.

Comment: Any idea how to detect whether using Mobile/Ipad with the help of JQuery/Javascript ?

Comment: I would give a try, would let you know the status, thanks for your help.

Comment: As per that discussion either I have to use Javascript userAgent or modernizer framework. Is there any other way to detect devices?

Comment: Keep reading that stackoverflow article...other people have made non-jQuery suggestions

Comment: Thanks for your help, I succeeded :)

Comment: actually, detecting the browser is _bad behavior_®. This was discouraged a long time ago - that's why things like Modernizr have born. For this use case you should, actually, simply detect the window size and load accordingly. That's exactly what you need - because, in the end, your iPad user might be using it in landscape mode, right? Browser detection won't help you there ;)

Answer (score 0):

So I used a differen't approach and sorry this might be ugly to read, but the video is just embedded deep into the HTML.

```
    <section style="height: 1098px;" class="main-content section-full-area no-padding">
    <a href="#second-section" class="scroll-btn-full-area">
        <i class="scroll-btn-down-icon animated-opacity"></i> 
    </a>
    <div class="video-section-container">
        <div class="video-overlay" style="background-color:#000000; opacity: 0.65;"></div>
        <div class="mobile-video-image" ></div>
        <div style="width: 1920px; height: 1098px;" class="video-wrap">
            <div style="width: 1920px; height: 800px;" id="mep_0" class="mejs-container svg video mejs-video">
                <div class="mejs-inner">
                    <div class="mejs-mediaelement">
                        <video style="width: 1990px; height: 1120px;" src="about_files/final.mp4" class="video" preload="auto" loop="" autoplay="autoplay"  height="800" width="1920">
                            <source type="video/mp4" src="about_files/final.mp4">
                            <source type="video/mp4" src="about_files/final.mp4">
                        </video>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="mejs-layers">
                        <div style="width: 1920px; height: 800px; display: none;" class="mejs-overlay mejs-layer">
                            <div class="mejs-overlay-loading">
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none; width: 1920px; height: 800px;" class="mejs-overlay mejs-layer">
                            <div class="mejs-overlay-error"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none; width: 1920px; height: 0px;" class="mejs-overlay mejs-layer mejs-overlay-play">
                            <div style="margin-top: -20px;" class="mejs-overlay-button"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="visibility: hidden; display: block;" class="mejs-controls">
                        <div class="mejs-button mejs-playpause-button mejs-pause">
                            <button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play/Pause" aria-label="Play/Pause"></button>
                        </div>
                    <div class="mejs-time mejs-currenttime-container">
                        <span class="mejs-currenttime">00:18</span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width: 1756px;" class="mejs-time-rail">
                        <span style="width: 1738px;" class="mejs-time-total">
                        <span style="display: none;" class="mejs-time-buffering"></span>
                        <span style="width: 1738px;" class="mejs-time-loaded"></span>
                        <span style="width:  540px;" class="mejs-time-current"></span>
                        <span style="left: 537px;" class="mejs-time-handle"></span>
                        <span class="mejs-time-float">
                            <span class="mejs-time-float-current">00:00</span>
                            <span class="mejs-time-float-corner"></span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="mejs-time mejs-duration-container">
                    <span class="mejs-duration">01:00</span>
                </div>
                <div class="mejs-button mejs-volume-button mejs-mute">
                    <button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Mute Toggle" aria-label="Mute Toggle"></button>
                <div style="display: none;" class="mejs-volume-slider">
                    <div class="mejs-volume-total"></div>
                    <div style="height: 36.8px; top: 17.2px;" class="mejs-volume-current"></div>
                    <div style="top: 15px;" class="mejs-volume-handle"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mejs-button mejs-fullscreen-button">
                <button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Fullscreen" aria-label="Fullscreen"></button> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mejs-clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also used an mp4. Some browsers don't support .webm (Firefox)